# How to fix: The type or namespace name 'MouseLook' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Help. I was making code for the game on Unity, but something went wrong and I got 2 errors:

1. error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MouseLook' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2. error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PlayerMovement' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please help!

I tried to create a game on Unity, and using the photon network I created multiplayer. But I got these 2 errors, I do not understand how to solve them. Please help me I will be very grateful

code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class IsMine : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private PlayerMovement _playerMovement;
    [SerializeField] private MouseLook _mouseLook;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _camera;
    [SerializeField] private PhotonView _photonView;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _playerModel;

    void Start()
    {
        if (!_photonView.IsMine)
        {
            _playerMovement.enabled = false;
            _mouseLook.enabled = false;
            _camera.SetActive(false);
            _playerModel.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this context 'PlayerMovement' and 'MouseLook' are both classes. Somewhere in your unity solution you need to have both of these classes that the game can make a valid reference to.